# How to convert .py to mac installer file?

Tags: python, macos, web-scraping, terminal, pyinstaller

I've created a python app and wanted to convert it into an executable mac installer file. I've already created .exe for Windows, but when it comes to Mac, I tried running the following commands:

```
sudo pyinstaller Notify.py -n Notify --windowed --noconfirm --clean
```

After running this code in the terminal, I was able to get **Notify** app but when I try to run it, it is not running. And usually shows a terminal window (showing logout), and later nothing happens.

I've also followed all the dependencies listed here: http://eddiejackson.net/wp/?p=21586

Comment: create executable using cx_freeze, it will support Mac,Linux and Windows compatablity, but it won't be in onefile mode like pyinstaller

Comment: Thanks. But can you tell me the exact process? Please. I'm entirely new to this.

Comment: https://pypi.org/project/py2app/

Comment: pip install cx-Freeze Read here...https://cx-freeze.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html and

Comment: I use pyinstaller, and I found here how to do. In short you should configure setup for different target, and you need a script to create the app (from the files). So: look better, we have the solution (sorry I cannot help more, it took me some time to find it, and I've not written down where to find the different steps)